# Google cloud functions do not work with ifttt

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, ifttt

I created an `ifttt Applet` using **youtube video like** as a trigger with a **webhook(https cloud function)** as an action. I get an error on `iffttt` that there was a problem with the webhooks service. I tested it with https://requestb.in url and `ifttt` works with it. is there something i'm missing to do too get a webhook working with cloud functions?  I have already enabled billing for the function project.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for the webhook, an image of the IFTTT action configuration, and any logs that might have been generated when IFTTT called it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: That is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked functions logs to begin with. I assumed it never ran. There was a error in my code, I was using JSON.parse() that was leading to error. Now it is functional.